# How to load C++ dlls of the same name in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, runtime, badimageformatexception

I have two C++ WinApi(only x64 arch) dlls of the same names, which contain API of some project, for example C:\first\MyDll.dll and C:\second\MyDll.dll.
I can't rename it in my case.
So they can't be loaded in Reference Manager beacause they have the same names.

`DLLImport` can load only method, but i need to load some COM intefaces, guids, etc

What ideas you have?

**Thanks in advance everyone**

Comment: create two class projects and put one in each class.

Comment: Not sure the right way to do what you want but the ````Assembly.Load*```` methods (and the Assembly type itself) are for loading managed assemblies. You want to load a natove assembly. Maybe something in the System.Runtime, or System.Runtime.InteropServices namespaces could help.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create another unmanaged dll and use it to load the dll you want... Or maybe use unmanaged/native stuff in a C++/CLI project to load them.

Comment: As @paramecium points out, only managed assemblies (i.e. those that have an assembly manifest) can be loaded using `Assembly.Load*`. Generally, if you want to call into *unmanaged* code, you either use COM Interop or P/Invoke (calling exported C functions). What are you trying to call, and how?

Comment: P/Invoke export only methods, i need all data from dll(interfaces, uuids etc)
About COM Interop will read